# Js error when first time loading site magento 2 in chrome browser

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Js error when **first time** loading  site magento 2 in **chrome browser**. Firefox, and explorer no problem. One of the problem is here.  http://prntscr.com/kso59y

Comment: @Andranik have you added any custom js ? This seems to be a jquery issue , may be the js file is not loaded . also please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin

Comment: please share some lines of code in which error is generating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136389)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ksrc41